# Composite object in typescript

Tags: typescript

I am currently learning the usage of typescript

```
class User extends AdminObject {
      FirstName: string;
      LastName: string;
      Login: string;
      UserPassword: Password;
}
```

Can i create a class with composite object?

Comment: What's the relation between your code and composite objects ?

Comment: By composite object i want to refer to a not basic object (string,number..).

In my exemple: i want know if i can add the passowrd type in the Properties of my User Class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
interface IComponent {
    Name: string;
    doSomething(foo: string);
}

class Composite implements IComponent {
    public Name: string;
    public Children: Array<IComponent>;

    public doSomething(foo: string){
        // do stuff
    } 
}

class Leaf implements IComponent {
    public Name: string;

    public doSomething(foo: string){
        // do other stuff
    } 
}
```

According to your comment, this is not really what you're waiting for. I was assuming Composite pattern. But this code still shows that yes, you can refer to whatever type you already defined in TypeScript, as long as it is accessible from your code (potentially using `export` to make those types available from other modules).